# Refreshing multiple WebBrowsers at one time

Tags: vb.net

I am adding web browsers programmatically to tab pages and incrementing the names by one (WebBrowser1, WebBrowser2, etc.)

I want to be able to refresh all the browsers at once when a button is clicked.

I've tried looping through the controls and calling out the WebBrowsers to refresh them, but havent had any luck. I also read about adding the WebBrowsers to an array and then using that array to refresh them, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Here is my code for adding the web browsers to the tab pages:

```
Dim newTab As TabPage = New TabPage With {.Text = Path.GetFileName(HTMLReportFile)}
Dim wb As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser With {.Name = "WebBrowser" & (TabControl2.TabPages.Count + 1), .Location = New Point(3, 3), .Width = 725, .Height = 496}

            newTab.Controls.Add(wb)
            wb.Navigate(HTMLReportFile)
            TabControl2.Controls.Add(newTab)
```

I know there's a simple solution to this, but I am stumped. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Add the `WebBrowser` objects to a `List(Of WebBrowser)`. Add them to each new `TabPage` when required. `Refresh()` the `WebBrowsers` looping the List. `Dispose()` of the objects in the List when you're done with them (or when closing the application).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jimi, it makes life so much simpler to keep it all wrapped into a List(Of WebBrowser).

The code would be something along these lines:

```
    Dim wbTabs As New List(Of WebBrowser)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newTab As TabPage = New TabPage With {.Text = "FileName"}
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser With {.Name = "WebBrowser" & (TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1), .Location = New Point(3, 3), .Width = 725, .Height = 496}

    wbTabs.Add(wb)

    newTab.Controls.Add(wb)
    wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    TabControl1.Controls.Add(newTab)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each WB In wbTabs
        WB.Refresh()
    Next

End Sub
```

If for whatever reason you *really* don't want to wrap them into a list you could use the following to loop through each tab, find the WebBrowser element and refresh them accordingly:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For Each tPage As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
            For Each Cntrl As Control In tPage.Controls
                If Cntrl.GetType Is GetType(WebBrowser) Then
                    Cntrl.Refresh()
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```